# nullpointer exception when using request.getpart

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have two jsp files. At test3.jsp I select a file and input version then display it.
test3.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<form action="test2.jsp" method="post"
  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
    <input type="text" name="version"/>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

test2.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" 
%><%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
<%@page import="java.lang.System"%>
<%@page import=" javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.http.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body><table>
</table>
</body>
</html>
<%
// Part filePart = request.getPart("file"); // Retrieves <input type="file" name="file">
// String fileName = filePart.getSubmittedFileName();
out.println("<html>");
out.println("<head>");
out.println("</head>");
out.println("<body>"+request.getPart("version").getContentType());
out.println("</body>");
out.println("</html>");
%>
```

The upload part not finished yet, just for the above code I got below error.

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:473)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>     at
>   io.undertow.jsp.JspFileHandler.handleRequest(JspFileHandler.java:32)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   org.apache.jsp.test2_jsp._jspService(test2_jsp.java:124)  at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)  at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
>     ... 42 more

Can anyone give me some idea what's the issue?Thx.

Comment: you should use request.getParameter("version") if you want to retrieve value of version from form.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking part in "text" field (version), try with "file"